# Python script to automate number of available ip addresses on my subnet

Tags: python, networking, automation

Can someone help me with creating a python script that will do these things. I am trying to learn how to automate things.

Run nmap quick scan and export to text file:

```
nmap -T4 -F 10.0.0.1/24 > nmap.txt
```

Cut text to list of IP's:

```
cat nmap.txt | grep "Nmap scan report" | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d '.' -f 4 > ip_sub.txt
```

Create list of possible hosts (list from 1-255):

```
python -c 'for i in range(255): print i+1' > ip_all.txt
```

Sort files to prepare for diff (could have done this earlier):

```
cat ip_all.txt | sort -n > ip_all_sort.txt
cat ip_sub.txt | sort -n > ip_sub_sort.txt
```

Create diff file in columns:

```
diff -y ip_all_sort.txt ip_sub_sort.txt > ip_sub_all_diff.txt
```

Now, count how many unused IP addresses:

```
grep '<' -o ip_sub_all_diff.txt | wc -l
```

Comment: Sorry, what's your question?

Comment: Is it not working? What is the expected behavior versus the actual behavior?

Comment: You do realize that not all networks are `/24` networks with only 254 (not 255) usable host addresses. For example, a `/8` network will give you 16,777,214 usable host addresses. When you get to IPv6, the standard network size is `/64` with 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 usable addresses per network (all addresses on an IPv6 network are usable).

Comment: Sorry, if I wasn't clear. I do realize that all networks are not /24. Mine is, for now. I want to monitor that for now to see when I might be outgrowing it. Everything is working fine this way, I was just wanting help writing a python script that would be able to automate this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with installing nmap to python.

```
pip install python-nmap
```

usage looks like this:

```
import nmap

nm = nmap.PortScanner() 
nm.scan('10.0.0.1')
res = nm.all_hosts()
print res
```

This way you can skip the whole writing to text files part. `res` contains your information you can use regex for the grep part, iterate over the results with your for loop.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for!, Thank you, @Rizzit.